Punctuation: "enfants ╵du"
Ref: https://www.bible.com/bible/21/HOS.2.BDS
Almost every line contains ╵.  Is this something normal in French or unique to this bible version?  I haven't seen it in any French book I have (tried to) read.

C'est peut-être un guide pour la scansion.

From what I can see, they're all on te'amim (cantillation / scansion marks) in the Hebrew, but since there are many te'amim with different pausal and melodic values but only one ╵ apparently used for all of them, I'm not sure if they are what it's trying to capture or not. That said, since the most important te'amim are represented by line breaks and the strongest (sof passuk) naturally by a verse number, perhaps this is just a way of representing the minor ones as well.

Not knowing anything of Biblical Hebrew, my 1st thought is, these would mark ends of lines in the original, or ends of verses. The usual punctuation when French verses are quoted inline is to separate them with slashes "/".

Anyway: no it is not standard and I would expect the convention to be explained in the Editor's foreword.

But to see the editor's foreward, I'd have to buy a copy of the book.  :-)  Anyway, if I am trying to acquire more French by listening to the audio while following along in the text, I might be better off without them?

@FrançoisJurain Knowing something of Biblical Hebrew, they don't mark ends of lines or verses in the original :) They roughly correspond to cantillation marks, which are mostly much smaller subdivisions of text. Both of these roughly align with syntactic group breaks, since these are useful for guiding intonation, which explains the overlap.

You are quoting an extract from La Bible du Semeur¹. The sign | is not a punctuation sign and is specific to this particular translation of the Bible. Here is an extract from the foreword of a later edition of the Bible based on the Bible du Semeur²  where it is explained that | indicates the  French free verse division:


Le signe |
L’une des particularités de la Bible du Semeur est d’avoir donné aux textes poétiques une forme plus recherchée, s’apparentant à la poésie, dans la traduction. La solution qui a paru possible est l’adoption d’une certaine régularité rythmique : sans que l’on ait pu avoir toujours un même nombre de syllabes par vers pour un même poème, on a au moins un rythme syllabique pair ou impair. Les textes sont ainsi découpés en vers libres, qui ne correspondent souvent pas aux segments de l’hébreu. La disposition du texte laisse apparaître les lignes de l’original, et le découpage en vers libres français est signalé par le signe |.



¹A twentieth-century French version of the Bible meant to be understood by as many people as possible, and evangelical Protestant in orientation.
² I am not providing a link to a source because it ends up on a commercial site. It can be found on the internet with the help of a search engine.  

"to be understood by as many people as possible" makes it a good choice for my purpose, which is exposure to modern French rather than religious accuracy.
